# Right triangle inscribed in a circle with the equation of the circle is $r=2a\:cos\left(\theta \right)$

Tags: geometry

How to prove that the equation of the circle (the image given below) is $r=2a\:cos\left(\theta \right)$ using polar coordinates? Please anyone help me, I've been stuck in this problem for like 2 hours without result and been looking for some hints in google but don't know which step I should take first. Thank you so much if you want to give me a hint to solve this problem.

[image: the right triangle $OPQ$ inscribed in a circle]

Comment: Hint: the equation is not $r=2acos\theta$. When $\theta=\pi$, you should have negative $r$, and the max $r$ you can have is $2a$, when $\theta=0$, which is not the case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $$\cos \theta=\frac{OP}{OQ}=\frac{r}{2a},$$

Hnece $r=2a \cos\theta.$

Comment: Don't forget that $OQ\neq 2a$ and that it should be said that this is not defined for every $\theta$.

Comment: Is this equation only worked for right triangle inscribed in a circle so it safe to say that $r=2a\:cos\left(\theta \right)$? @Martigan btw, thank you so much for you both, sir!

Comment: @alethiologist This is not right, since $OQ=4a$!